# Flatten Invoice Header with Invoice Lines in Kettle

Tags: pentaho, kettle, flatten, pentaho-data-integration, denormalized

If you have an invoice header with several values (invoice #, date, location) and an unknown amount of invoice lines with several values (product, price, tax), is there a way to flatten this data to one row that extends in cases where the quantity of invoice lines varies by invoice?

---

Input Example-

```
{"InvoiceRecords": [{
    "InvoiceDate": "8/9/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "InvoiceLocation": "002",
    "InvoiceNumber": "2004085",
    "InvoiceRecordHeaderDetails": [{
        "InvNum": "2004085",
        "Location": "002",
        "InvDate": "8/9/2017 12:00:00 AM"
    }],
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetails": [{
        "UniqueID": "3939934",
        "InvNum": "2004085",
        "LINEITEM": "1",
        "CUSTID": "PREAA",
        "DEPTID": "320306",
        "PRODID": "088856",
        "ProdDesc": "STATE UST",
        "Unitprice": "0.003",
        "QuantShare": "237.5",
        "TaxRate": "7.25",
        "taxamount": "0.05"
    }],
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetails": [{
        "InvNum": "2004085",
        "LineItem": "1",
        "UniqueID": "34",
        "taxCode": "SALES TAX",
        "taxrate": "7.25",
        "maxtax": "0"
    }]
}]}
```

I need all the items on the same row (allowing for there to be more than one line item and/or more than one Tax Code items on a given Invoice Record.

---

Output Example (note: "_n" below in reference to undetermined amount of invoice lines and tax rows possible):

```
{"InvoiceRecords": [{
    "InvoiceDate": "8/9/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "InvoiceLocation": "002",
    "InvoiceNumber": "2004085",
    "InvoiceRecordHeaderDetailsInvNum": "2004085",
    "InvoiceRecordHeaderDetailsInvNumLocation": "002",
    "InvoiceRecordHeaderDetailsInvNumInvDate": "8/9/2017 12:00:00 AM",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsUniqueID_1": "3939934",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsInvNum_1": "2004085",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsLINEITEM_1": "1",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsCUSTID_1": "PREAA",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsDEPTID_1": "320306",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsPRODID_1": "088856",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsProdDesc_1": "STATE UST",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsUnitprice_1": "0.003",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsQuantShare_1": "237.5",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsTaxRate_1": "7.25",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailstaxamount_1": "0.05",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsInvNum_1": "2004085",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsLineItem_1": "1",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsUniqueID_1": "34",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailstaxCode_1": "SALES TAX",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailstaxrate_1": "7.25",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsmaxtax_1": "0",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsUniqueID_n": "3939934",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsInvNum_n": "2004085",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsLINEITEM_n": "1",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsCUSTID_n": "PREAA",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsDEPTID_n": "320306",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsPRODID_n": "088856",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsProdDesc_n": "STATE UST",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsUnitprice_n": "0.003",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsQuantShare_n": "237.5",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailsTaxRate_n": "7.25",
    "InvoiceRecordLineItemDetailstaxamount_n": "0.05",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsInvNum_n": "2004085",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsLineItem_n": "1",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsUniqueID_n": "34",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailstaxCode_n": "SALES TAX",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailstaxrate_n": "7.25",
    "InvoiceTaxCodeDetailsmaxtax_n": "0"
}]}
```

Thanks!

Comment: A three line example would be most welcome !

Comment: Of course there is. The issue is there are lots of them, depending on the shape of your data. For the input you have one row followed by an arbitrary number of rows. And for the output you want one row per invoice. In what type of data do you want your lineitem data: a string? an array? an XML? a JSON?

Comment: @AlainD, I posted an example.  Thanks!

Comment: So the input is one row followed by an arbitrary number of rows. The output is one row containing a JSON which is an array of {header, [item], footer}.

Comment: The input is the input example above.  The output needs to be an array of {header, [item], footer} where the [item] is all of the [items] from the example in the one output [item] (like output example 2 above.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an example of a similar question in the `samples` directory which sits nearby you spoon.bat. Have a look at the `samples/transformation/XML Add` and survive the first choc: they do something much more complex, just to show all what is possible.

In your case, split with a `Switch/Case`, the input stream in header, items and manage to keep the InvoiceNumber on each (more on this later). Convert the three stream into JSON (with JSON Output or, maybe easier, with a `Javascript`). Then you `Group by` the items by InvoiceNumber. Join the three flows by InvoiceNumber, for which I suggest a `lookup stream` in the header stream then an other `lookup stream` in the footer stream. With an other `javascript` and treating the data as string, you can build the JSON row in the format { header, [item], footer}, which you can `Group by` with a concatenation to have only one row.

Some work, but rather standard, except for the tricky part of the get the InvoiceNumber on the items and footer as they have disappeared from the flow. For that you can use fact that the `javascript` preserve the values unless redefined. Add a new start script [right click on the Script1 on the tab top, add a copy, right click on the Script1_0 just created, and define it as Start script].

On this start script:

```
var PrevInvoiceNumber = -1;
```

On the main script:

```
if(InvoiceNumber && PrevInvoiceNumber!=InvoiceNumber)
    PrevInvoiceNumber = InvoiceNumber
```

Then you should see the data with on each line the PrevInvoiceNumber which is equal to the expected InvoiceNumber of the invoice.[image]

Comment: I think it is the right answer to the wrong question. And I guess you prefer me to correct the answer that you to correct the question. But it's late by my time, you'll have to wait for tomorrow. Basically, it is the same,except you read the data with 3 JSON input (header, item, footer) and keep the InvoiceNr (which is possible on the JSON input). Produce a _n with a sequence number, make the key:value pair, split the fields to row, sort them and group them in a single output.